# Anko Coroutines - async BG not returning anything

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, anko

I am new to Anko and I want to perform some work on background thread so I found couroutines solution for it( Using kotlin)

So I used Anko couroutines -> and find this **bg** method to make the progress in the background.

But post process execution is not working. Any idea?

I tried with await() and completed() both but nothing is working.

```
fun GetBitmapFromUri(uri: ArrayList<Uri>) {

    showProgressDialog()
    async(UI) {
        val result = bg {
            convert2Bitmap(uri)
        }

        transfer(result.await())
    }
}

fun convert2Bitmap(uri: ArrayList<Uri>): ArrayList<Bitmap> {
    val imagesUri = ArrayList<Bitmap>()

    for (i in 0 until uri.size) {
        imagesUri.add(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri[i]))

        print("Convert $i")
    }

    return imagesUri
}
```